# N1QL - How to get all document's IDs as a simple JSON array?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Is there a way to get all document IDs as a simple JSON array?

If I do `select meta(t).id from myBucket t;` I get them in an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1002929"
  },
  ...
```

But I'd like to have them in a simple array like:

`["1002929", ...]`

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Do

```
SELECT RAW META(t).id
FROM myBucket t;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works if I try directly in Couchbase, but it doesn't work if I do it via Spring Data for Couchbase. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: It should be possible through direct template interface findByN1QL. It wouldn't work with repository methods as they need to deserialize back to entity.

Comment: Actually, you would need directly query through bucket template as findByN1QL also looks for CAS.  N1qlQueryResult res =  bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple("select raw meta().id from `travel-sample`"));

Comment: Hi @subhashni! Thank you so far! I tried it with `bucket().query(N1qlQuery.simple("select raw meta(t).id from `backinstock` t"));` but wasn't successful. :(

Comment: Hi Kris apologies for notifying earlier, Couchbase java client had raw  supported from 2.3.0 release. SDC had been using client version 2.2.8  until recently now SDC has been upgraded to use the client version 2.4.1. The current build snapshot has it,  Ingalls next SR release or next immediate release Kay M2 with SDC 3.0 has support for it.